# Run Bash file on Android studio

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, adb

I have a script file that I want to run from the terminal in my Android studio.
(I want to target all the devices with this script.)

This is the script file with the name `run_all.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
adb devices | while read -r line
do
if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ "$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')" = "device" ]
then
    device=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "$device" "$@" ...
    adb -s "$device" "$@"
fi
done
```

I run it like this in the terminal:

```
./run_all.sh
```

But I'm getting this result:

```
./run_all.sh: command not found
```

I can't find the problem.

Comment: If the file is called `run_all.sh`, why would you use `./adb_install.sh`

Comment: Was a mistake in writing the question, the question updated. thanks

Comment: Could you explain what the bash file does?

Comment: Ok. What is your directory structure? The script exists in the root of your project, and you're running your command from the same directory? Is the script executable?